# Subtract months from year in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

implement function `subtract_months` to subtract `n` number of months from a given year and month.

Inputs: Is a list of tuples `[(year1, month1, months_to_subtract1), (year2, month2, months_to_subtract2), ...]` 
where, year is a 4 digit integer
month is an integer value between 1 to 12, 1=January, 2=February, ... 12=December) and 
months_to_subtract is an integer

Output: Is a list of tuples `[(result_year1, result_month1), (result_year2, result_month2), ...]` 
year (4 digit integer) month (integer value between 1 to 12, 1=January, 2=February, ... 12=December)

For example: subtract 3 months from May 2020. This should result in an output Feb 2020
In this example inputs: year=2020 month=5
output: year=2020 month=2

```
def subtract_months(input_list):
    output_list = []
    #TODO: implement your code here

    return output_list
```

Comment: If you have a specific issue while solving this yourself you can ask here.

Answer (score 2):

## Solution I have come up with and it works well for all cases.

def subtract_Months(year,month,month_to_subtract) :

```
result_month = 0
result_year = 0
if month > (month_to_subtract % 12):
    result_month = (month - month_to_subtract) % 12 
    result_year = year - month_to_subtract // 12
else:        
    result_month = 12 - (month_to_subtract % 12) + month
    result_year = year - (month_to_subtract // 12 + 1)
    
return (result_year, result_month)
```

subtract_Months(2010,5,7)

> > (2009,10)

Answer (score 2):

Although Shubham's logic is correct, I would like to improve it as the input is a list of tuples and output is also a list of tuples. So instead of hard coding 3 arguments to the function, we'll give a list of tuples as an argument and then iterate over the tuples and list. Also, this should return a list of tuples.

```
def subtract_months(input_list):
list = []
output_list = []
for i in input_list:
    for j in i:
        list.append(j)
    if list[1] > (list[2] % 12) :
        result_month = (list[1] - list[2]) % 12
        result_year = list[0] - list[2] // 12
    else:
        result_month = 12 - (list[2] % 12 ) + list[1]
        result_year = list[0] - (list[2] // 12 + 1)
    listed = (result_year, result_month)
    output_list.append(listed)
    list = []
    
return output_list
```

Answer (score -1):

```py
def subtract_months(input_list):
    output_list = []
    #TODO: implement your code here
    year = [a_tuple[0] for a_tuple in input_list]
    month = [a_tuple[1] for a_tuple in input_list]
    month_to_subtract = [a_tuple[2] for a_tuple in input_list]
    for i in range(len(year)):
        result_month = 0
        result_year  = 0
        if month[i] > (month_to_subtract[i] % 12):
            result_month = (month[i] - month_to_subtract[i]) % 12
            result_year = year[i] - month_to_subtract[i] // 12
        else:
            result_month = 12 - (month_to_subtract[i] % 12) + month[i]
            result_year = year[i] - (month_to_subtract[i] // 12 + 1)
        output_tuple=(result_year,result_month)
        output_list.append(output_tuple)

    return output_list
```

Comment: you can use code block to put code that will make your answer looks good

Comment: Beside formatting, it is better to add an explanation fir your solution so other can generalize the idea for their own issue